# Relevel a factor

Tags: r, r-factor

There is given a unordered factor ID, a reference vector for the rank of each level and a label for each level. Now I want to order the ID's by given rank and after that I want to overrider the labels in the factor.

Could you give a advise if there is a better way to do so:

```
ID<-factor(c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,1)+10)
Rank<-c("11"=3,"12"=1,"13"=2)
Label<-c("11"="B","12"="A","13"="C")
ID.Rank<-factor(ID, levels=names(Rank),labels=Rank)
ID.Rank<-factor(ID.Rank, levels=sort(Rank),order=T)
ID.Label<-factor(ID, levels=names(Label),labels=Label)
data.frame(ID,ID.Rank,ID.Label)
### here is importent that ID.Rank has a certain order. 
factor(ID.Rank, labels=Label[match(levels(ID.Rank), Rank)])
```

Comment: I'm confused by the three labeling schemes.  You have ID, Rank, and Label, but since ID and Rank are both numeric, I don't know if the numbers corresponding to the labels refer to the IDs or the Ranks.  To be clearer, I would suggest making the IDs 11:13 and also showing your desired output.

Comment: @Aaron ID<-factor(sample(11:13,10,T));
ID;
idlvl<-levels(ID);
Rank<-c("11"=3,"12"=1,"13"=2);
idrank<-Rank[as.character(idlvl)];
ID<-factor(ID, labels=idrank);
ID<-factor(ID, levels=1:length(idrank),order=T);
ID;
Label<-c("11"="B","12"="A","13"="C");
idlabel<-Label[as.character(idlvl)];
factor(ID, levels=idrank, labels=idlabel);

Comment: This gives a different result than the first code, though.  Which is correct?

Comment: @Aaron, sry I edit my start post.

Comment: I don't yet understand what you want. You say they need the levels to be in a particular order ("by a given rank") but you don't actually say what order that is, and then you offer code that creates objects that presumably are not what you need. There are two kinds of order in a factor. The usual "order" is the levels for treatment contrasts, and the less commonly used "ordered factor" is constructed with the 'order'-argument.

Comment: @DWin, sry, I will describe again. I have IDs, each ID has rank and a label given by ID, Rank and Label. Now I want to relabel the IDs by Label and order the IDs by Rank.Taht it looks like the result above. And I spend alot time to found a readable solution but I couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, here is how you can solve the problem.

```
set.seed(2)
ID<-as.numeric(ID)
df1<-as.data.frame(ID)
> df1
   ID
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   2
5   3
6   2
7   3
8   3
9   2
10  3
df2<-as.data.frame(Rank)
df2$ID<-rownames(df2)
> df2
  Rank ID
1    3  1
2    1  2
3    2  3

df3<-merge(df1,df2,by="ID")
  ID Rank
1   1    3
2   1    3
3   2    1
4   2    1
5   2    1
6   3    2
7   3    2
8   3    2
9   3    2
10  3    2
```

`df3$Rank` is what you are looking as the final result. You can convert that to factor.

Updated as per comments: If you want the original order of ID:

```
df1$IDo<-rownames(df1)
df3
   ID IDo Rank
1   1   1    3
2   1   7    3
3   1   4    3
4   2   3    1
5   2   9    1
6   2  10    1
7   3   2    2
8   3   5    2
9   3   6    2
10  3   8    2
```

Comment: Thx, but in your solution I lost the order of Elements in the vector ID.

Comment: But, you can get that before using `merge` as `df1$IDo<-rownames(df1)`. See the updates

Answer (score 2):

```
 myFac <- factor(ID, levels=Rank, labels=names(Rank) )
 myFac
 [1] 3 3 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 3
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3

 match(levels(myFac), names(Label) )
[1] 1 2 3
 Label[match(levels(myFac), names(Label) )]
  1   2   3 
 "B" "A" "C" 
 levels(myFac) <- Label[match(levels(myFac), names(Label) )]
 myFac
#-----
 [1] C C A A C B B A A C
Levels: B < A < C
```

Comment: sry I think I did something wrong in my start post, so I am still confused. I edit my startpost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Rank` and `Label` are always in the same order, you just need to order the labels appropriately and then use them to create the ordered factor.

```
ID <- factor(c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,1)+10)
Rank <- c("11"=3,"12"=1,"13"=2)
Label <- c("11"="B","12"="A","13"="C")

Label <- Label[order(Rank)]
factor(ID, levels=names(Label), labels=Label, order=TRUE)
## [1] B A A C B C C A B B
## Levels: A < C < B
```