# How to "relevel" the levels in a column of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a similar question  as to [Relevel a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827532/relevel-a-factor):

I have a data.frame, df, consisting of n=200 row entires for df$id, df$time, df$age where 21 individual id are sampled numerous times. Current levels of df$id is:

```
> levels(df$id)

 [1] "boot" "clus" "cokl" "embr" "julp" "lanc" "lole" "mdrk" "mnst" "mrti"
[11] "omly" "puff" "rmmy" "savy" "smag" "spar" "sqrk" "tbmn" "thls" "vin" 
[21] "wino"
```

However,I would like to order of this to instead be:

```
> level.order$id
 [1] lanc mnst clus lole puff smag boot savy thls omly julp mrti vin  embr
[15] spar sqrk wino rmmy cokl mdrk tbmn
```

I understand there are a lot of similar inquiries about this, but I cannot figure it out with the examples at hand...

Comment: What class is level.order$id?

Comment: class for level.order$id is "factor". Technically this is the entire output when I run it: ```[1] lanc mnst clus lole puff smag boot savy thls omly julp mrti vin  embr
[15] spar sqrk wino rmmy cokl mdrk tbmn
       21 Levels: boot clus cokl embr julp lanc lole mdrk mnst mrti omly ... wino``` but i built the order of level.order$id form the datafame, so it holds the unwanted levels

Comment: Have you tried levels(df$id) <- as.character(level.order$id)

Comment: This in itself works: cub.fight.cubs.HZ$id  has levels that are now: lanc mnst clus lole puff smag boot savy thls ... tbmn. HOWEVER, this does not seem to apply to the entire dataset. For example, when I plot a ggplot(df, aes(x=age))+geom_hist()+facet_wrap(~id), the the title order of the plots are correct, but the actually plotted histograms are still in the original order of cub.fight.cubs.HZ$id .In fact str(df) shows the last line to read: - attr(*, "levels")= Factor w/ 21 levels "boot","clus",.. which is still not correct

Comment: @BillO'Brien Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder the levels by using the factor function rather than the relevel function.

```
df$id <- factor(df$id, levels = level.order$id)
```

Comment: Awesome, this applies the factor to the whole dataset. Can anyone explain why this is the case?